# display information from a csv-datei on a html-page without webserver

Tags: javascript, html, perl

I have a problem that I will like someone here to help me.
I have a Perl Script giving me informations about a csv-file.
its informations are:

**DATA:**

```
Number of compared parameters =7 

Current number of systems = 56

Date = 20150617 1:00:13 p.m.
```

Considering that the values can change.
I love that its information is displayed in an html page.
For that I will not like to use a webserver.
I was told that this was possible with javascript.
I will like someone here can help me.

for this reason I sent you my Perl Script and Front page (html).

**Perl Code:**

Comment: What is it exactly you want to do? Process Perl without a server? Display the output of a Perl script in html? Include a text file for output? What do you actually mean by "without a web server"? Do you just want the output to be HTML formatted?

Comment: I will like, Display the output of a Perl script in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to output your value to a HTML file in the script, this might help

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $date_1 = strftime "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S", localtime;
my $FileResult = 'result_1.csv'; 
open( my $FhResult, '>', $FileResult );
open my $fh, "<", "DATA.csv";
my ($h, $v) = (0, 0); 

while (<$fh> ) {last if (/^\d+\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*$/)} 
while (<$fh> ) {
next if (/^\s*$/);     
if (/^default\b/) {   
   $h = 0 + grep {!/^(default)?$/} map {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $_} split(/,/, $_);
 } else {                                                                  
   $v++;                                                                   
 }                                                                        
}
close($fh);

open FH ,">1.html";
print FH "  
    <html>    
        <head>         
            <meta charset=\"UTF-8\"/>
            <title>SYSTEMRESULTS</title>
            <link href=\"style.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/>
        </head>
         <body>

            <div id=\"section_1\">
                <font face=\"arial\"><h1><a id=\"sec_1_0\">S</a>ystem  <a id=\"sec_1_0\">P</a>arameter &emsp;<a id=\"sec_1_0\">C</a>ompare</h1></font>
            </div>


             <div id=\"section_3\"> 
             <font face=\"arial\" size=\"+2\">Current number of systems: $v </font> 
             </div>

             <div id=\"section_4\">
             <font face=\"arial\" size=\"+2\">Number of compared parameters: $h  </font> 
             </div>

             <div id=\"section_5\">
             <font face=\"arial\" size=\"+2\">Date:  $date_1</font>
             </div>

             <div id=\"section_6\"><a href=\"file/result_1.csv\">NEXT<img src=\"aiga.png\"/></a></div>

        </body>

        <div id=\"footer\">
          <p>&copy; 2015 copyright</p>
        </div>  

    </html>
    ";

close FH;

Output
1.html content:


    System Parameter  Compare

    Current number of systems: 56  

    Number of compared parameters: 7  

    Date: 20150617 1:00:13 p.m
```

Comment: Thank you for your well propositon Chandran

as I said values can change at any time.
when I see your proposal values are fixed, and it does not solve the pobleme

Comment: Those are test values Henri.. Please use the OPEN and PRINT html part from that snippet and add it in your script . Since u have $h, $v and $date_1 are dynamic value generated from your script.

Comment: how you put a perl code in html file? and get this output